# How can I identify certain symbols on a scanned form?

Tags: php

I'm building a web application in PHP, and part of the requirement is that I need to be able to quickly process data on a scanned copy of a fairly simple form, and save it to a database for later retrieval.

Given the following image

[image]

how can I identify and assign a database field a value of either true or false (true when it sees a tick, and false otherwise)?

I'm thinking along the following line of implementation:

I will keep two copies of the above image - the first will have ticks shown (as above), and the second will be a "clean" copy of the image with the borders left behind. Comparing between the two images will yield a difference; the difference will return either a value of true or false.

There are drawbacks as far as I can observe of the above implementation. What happens if the user scribbles something in it (as seen above) but it does not mean anything? How do I even ensure that the returned values of true or false are assigned to the appropriate columns in the database?

I don't have any code implementation at this point in time, and I'm not asking for it. Rather, I'm asking for guidance on where to look and how I can efficiently do this.

Comment: You'll need some kind of image recognition package.  And probably human review of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using OpenCV framework for PHP (https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP, http://mgdm.net/talks/confoo11/making-php-see.pdf) and use contour detection (or any other classificators) to find signs like "V" and skip false-positives.

Comment: Thank you, I've decided to experiment with this wrapper. I've marked yours as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [PHP OCR library](http://phpocr.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I will do thin in a following way: I will divide image into 2x6 grid and count black pixels in each row. If the number `n` contains in `<A;B>` then we can assume that row is checked. If someone scratch off an answer then `n` is larger than `B`.

So if `n` is in `<A;B>` range we can check its pattern - for example common part of the all marked rows because of user's handwriting.